# Python как пересжать фото и видео?

Tags: python, видео, photo

Подскажите, как я могу уменшить вес видео/фото используя python?

*Понимаю, что скорее всего потеряю качество, но мне это подходит*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше всего (что я нашёл) использовать `ffmpeg` пример команды: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4`. Код:

```py
import os 

os.system('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4')
```

`800k` - этот параметр отвечает за степень сжатия

P.S установил `ffmpeg`:

`pip install ffmpeg` (Windows)

`pip3 install ffmpeg` (Linux)